# What is the difference between VBScript's + and & operator?

Tags: string, vbscript, string-concatenation

On every site that talks about VBScript, the '`&`' operator is listed as the string concatenation operator. However, in some code that I have recently inherited, I see the '`+`' operator being used and I am not seeing any errors as a result of this. Is this an accepted alternative?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The + operator is overloaded, whereas the & operator is not.  The & operator only does string concatenation.  In some circles the & operator is used as a best practice because it is unambiguous, and therefore cannot have any unintended effects as a result of the overloading.

Comment: *`The + operator is overloaded`* -- *overloaded* in what sense?

Comment: @wolf in VB the + operator can do both addition and concatenation, depending on context.

Comment: Well, I already read this. I found the word *overloaded* itself so overloaded that I wished, the answer could be a little bit more precise in this point.

Answer (score 45):

The `&` operator does string concatenation, that is, forces operands to be converted to strings (like calling `CStr` on them first). `+`, in its turn, forces addition if one of the expressions is numeric. For example:

```
1 & 2
```

gives you `12`, whereas

```
1 + 2
"1" + 2
1 + "2"
```

give you `3`.

So, it is recommended to use `&` for string concatenation since it eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for specifying string number + number. Accepted answer doesn't mention vbscript converting numeric strings to numbers.

Answer (score 7):

`+` operator might backfire when strings can be interpreted as numbers. If you don't want nasty surprises use & to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases the + will throw an exception; for example the following:

```
Sub SimpleObject_FloatPropertyChanging(fvalue, cancel)
   'fvalue is a floating point number
   MsgBox "Received Event: " + fvalue
End Sub
```

You will get an exception when the COM object source fires the event - you must do either of the following:

```
MsgBox "Received Event: " & fvalue
```

or

```
MsgBox "Received Event: " + CStr(fvalue)
```

It may be best in either case to use `CStr(value)`; but using & per above comments for string concatenation is almost always best practice.