# Is there an option to put two integers next to each other in VBScript?

Tags: random, vbscript

I am trying to put two integers next to each other, but after some tries, I landed here and I can't get further. can you help me?

```
Dim max, min
max = 9
min = 0
Randomize
n1 = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))

max = 9
min = 0
Randomize
n2 = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))

x = MsgBox(n1, 1, "numbers")
x = MsgBox(n2, 1, "numbers")

numb = n1 + n2

x = MsgBox(numb, 1, "numbers")
```

I expect the two random generated numbers to be next to each other.

Comment: Do you mean like high byte low byte?  If you want to put two 8 bit integers into one 16 bit value, its low + (high * 256), if you just want to combine them as a string then CStr(n1) & CStr(n2)

Comment: `n1 & n2`?.....

Comment: What GSerg said. `n1` and `n2` are integers, so the `+` operator will add them, not concatenate them as you seem to expect. Also, `Randomize` should be called only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSerg brings the answer:

The line:

```
numb = n1 + n2
```

Should be changed to:

```
numb = n1 & n2
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Answer already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209159/692942).